# Mechanize HTTP Not found 404 Link

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm creating a scraper with Mechanize that runs through a csv of urls and downloads the image.

The problem is that some images are no longer there and I throw the 404 error of not found. I'm new to Ruby and I do not know how to work with the exceptions, I hope someone can help me.

I leave what I'm trying to do

```
agent = Mechanize.new

url = CSV.read("links.csv")

begin
    url.each do |url|
        puts url
        agent.get(url.first).save
    end
rescue Net::HTTPNotFound  => e
    puts e.response_code 
    agent = e.agent
end
```

The error it gives me is:

```
/home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:323:in `fetch': 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for http://www.rockauto.com/info/915/FCA6366_Fronp__ra_p.jpg -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
    from descargaimagenes.rb:34:in `fetch_with_retry'
    from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize.rb:464:in `get'
/home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:323:in `fetch': 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for http://www.rockauto.com/info/915/FCA6366_Fronp__ra_p.jpg -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
    from descargaimagenes.rb:34:in `fetch_with_retry'
    from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize.rb:464:in `get'
```

Comment: Just so you know, that url really returns a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Mechanize::ResponseCodeError` exception:

> This error is raised when Mechanize encounters a response code it does
>   not know how to handle. Currently, this exception will be thrown if
>   Mechanize encounters response codes other than 200, 301, or 302. Any
>   other response code is up to the user to handle.

And to move the rescue inside the each block, this way you go to the url, save the image, and in case the resource can't be found, print the response code.

```
[
  'http://www.rockauto.com/Images/whatsnew1.jpg?1512928800',
  'http://www.rockauto.com/info/915/FCA6366_Fronp__ra_p.jpg',
  'http://www.rockauto.com/Images/whatsnew2.jpg?1512928800'
].each do |url|
  begin
    agent.get(url).save
  rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
    puts e.response_code 
  end
end
```

There are two working urls, the one in the middle isn't working, and you should get the two images corresponding to each working url.